# How would i fetch old embed messages going back 30 days and combine those values [Discord.js V12]

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to **fetch old embed messages** going back **30 days** and each embed has a number in 1 of the fields and then combine those numbers to a total like **10 + 4 + 6 = 20**
I would be doing this every 30 days, probably with a command
how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recursively fetch messages from the last message currently present in the text channel and check if each message isn't outside the time range of 30 days. If it was inside the range I would check if the message has embed, if yes i would try to get the field value with the number and add it to some output variable. When I would find a message that is outside the time range I would stop fetching and return/do something with the output variable.

Begin with recursive function going through all the messages in a text channel. For example fetch 10 messages, check the dates. If we are still in the 30 day period fetch another 10 messages dating before the oldest message of the previous fetch and so on. The `fetch()` has arguments for specifying the message from which start fetching. So you don't fetch the same messages over and over again. Also note that the maximum number of messages you can fetch by one fetch call is 100 I think.

Comment: awesome, not sure how I would begin though

Comment: Begin with recursive function going through all the messages in a text channel. For example fetch 10 messages, check the dates. If we are still in the 30 day period fetch another 10 messages dating before the oldest message of the previous fetch and so on. The `fetch()` has arguments for specifying the message from which start fetching. So you don't fetch the same messages over and over again. Also note that the maximum number of messages you can fetch by one fetch call is 100 I think.

Comment: You should be putting that in your answer, not the comments.

Comment: @MrMythical I have put it in the answer then.

Comment: @Mathias AC If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal it helped but I have never worked with recursive functions and dates so now I am having trouble with that

Comment: @Mathias AC I think there will be a lot of posts on those topics. And not just on stack overflow. Also If you don't want recursion, you can just use while loop for example. Recursion is just how I personally would solve the problem. It's up to you. Be creative and good luck.

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal I can't seem to figure it out but I will keep trying, maybe you would be able to give me an example?

Comment: @MathiasAC You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68328614/9776840).

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal thank you but its an empty message when it's an embed
any ideas?

Comment: @MathiasAC I recommend you to start a new question about your current problem. You can read [how to ask a good question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us what you have tried and what does not work as you expected. You can include snippets of your code, etc.