# Pull info from discord server

Tags: cron, discord.js

I have the below cron job scheduled to run every minute to update a time in an embed.

```js
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function () {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM events WHERE closed = 'No'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err

        rows.slice().forEach(row => {
            const channel = row.channel
            const messageID = row.messageID

            bot.channels.cache.get(channel).messages.fetch(messageID).then(message => {
                const embed = message.embeds[0]

                let now = Date.now()
                const targetDate = new Date(`${row.event_date} ${row.event_time}:00`)
                var difference = (targetDate - now) / 1000;
                var days = Math.floor(difference / (3600 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((difference - (days * (3600 * 24))) / 3600);
                var minutes = Math.floor((difference - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);

                let timeTill;

                if (days > 0) {
                    timeTill = `${days} Days ${hours} Hours ${minutes} Min`
                } else if (days === 0 && hours > 0) {
                    timeTill = `${hours} Hours ${minutes} Min`
                } else if (days === 0 && hours === 0) {
                    timeTill = `${minutes} Min`
                } else if (difference <= 0) {
                    timeTill = `Event Started - get with <@!${row.hostID}> to join up in-game.`
                }

                embed.fields[9] = {
                    name: 'Starts in:',
                    value: `${timeTill}`,
                    inline: false
                }
                message.edit(new Discord.MessageEmbed(embed));
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Works just fine but I want to take the work load off my website server and just have the bot search for the information needed. Here is what I have so far but it doesn't do anything. Doesn't error, don't update the embed. Nothing. Pretty sure I'm overlooking something and just need another set of eyes to tell me what that is.

```js
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function () {
    bot.channels.cache.filter((channel) => channel.name.endsWith('events')).forEach((channel) => {
        channel.messages.cache.filter((message) => {
            const embed = message.embeds[0]
    
            let messageID;
            let event_date;
            let event_time;
    
            if (!embed) {
                return
            } else {
                if (embed.color === 65280) {
                    messageID = message.id
                    event_date = message.embeds[0].fields[0].value
                    event_time = message.embeds[0].fields[1].value
                } else {
                    return
                }
            }
            let now = Date.now()
            const targetDate = new Date(`${event_date} ${event_time}:00`)
            var difference = (targetDate - now) / 1000;
            var days = Math.floor(difference / (3600 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((difference - (days * (3600 * 24))) / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((difference - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        
            let timeTill;
        
            if (days > 0) {
                timeTill = `${days} Days ${hours} Hours ${minutes} Min`
            } else if (days === 0 && hours > 0) {
                timeTill = `${hours} Hours ${minutes} Min`
            } else if (days === 0 && hours === 0) {
                timeTill = `${minutes} Min`
            } else if (difference <= 0) {
                timeTill = `Event Started - get with <@!${row.hostID}> to join up in-game.`
            }
        
            embed.fields[9] = {
                name: 'Starts in:',
                value: `${timeTill}`,
                inline: false
            }
            message.edit(new Discord.MessageEmbed(embed))
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code:

```js
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function () {
    bot.channels.cache.filter((channel) => channel.name.endsWith('events')).forEach((channel) => {
        channel.messages.fetch({
            limit: 100
        }).then(messages => {
            messages.forEach(message => {
                if (message.embeds.length > 0) {
                    const embed = message.embeds[0]

                    let messageID;
                    let event_date;
                    let event_time;

                    if (embed.color === 65280) {
                        messageID = message.id
                        event_date = message.embeds[0].fields[0].value
                        event_time = message.embeds[0].fields[1].value.slice(0, -4)

                        let now = Date.now()
                        const targetDate = new Date(`${event_date} ${event_time}:00`)
                        var difference = (targetDate - now) / 1000;
                        var days = Math.floor(difference / (3600 * 24));
                        var hours = Math.floor((difference - (days * (3600 * 24))) / 3600);
                        var minutes = Math.floor((difference - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);

                        let timeTill;

                        if (days > 0) {
                            timeTill = `${days} Days ${hours} Hours ${minutes} Min`
                        } else if (days === 0 && hours > 0) {
                            timeTill = `${hours} Hours ${minutes} Min`
                        } else if (days === 0 && hours === 0) {
                            timeTill = `${minutes} Min`
                        } else if (difference <= 0) {
                            timeTill = `Event Started - get with <@!${row.hostID}> to join up in-game.`
                        }

                        embed.fields[9] = {
                            name: 'Starts in:',
                            value: `${timeTill}`,
                            inline: false
                        }
                        message.edit(new Discord.MessageEmbed(embed)).catch(error => {
                            console.error(error);
                        })
                        console.log(`Event ${message.embeds[0].author.name} has been edited. New start time is ${timeTill}.`)
                    } else {
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    return
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the messages you are trying to find might not be cached. The `channel.messages.cache` will only contain messages that were sent after the bot was started. If you want to go through older messages, you will need to [fetch the messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch). You might want to take a look at [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328613/how-to-fetch-messages-until-a-specific-date) about fetching messages until a specific date.

Comment: That got me on the right path, I'm posting my finished code now. Although I did tweak it just a bit more.

Comment: So the cron job stops running all by itself now. It will run for a few hours, then without throwing any error that I can find logged, just stop. Ideas?

Comment: Why do you think the cron job stopped?

Comment: I have no idea, the bot didn't crash or anything, I didn't know if there was some DIscord API rule that I was unaware of that would prevent the cronjob from running every min. IDK

Comment: You can try logging every run of the cron job with time for example, like that you will know for sure that it stopped. If you are certain that the cron job stopped without a trace or error or anything. Also for double checking you might wrap the whole cron job function body inside of a try/catch. So you are certain that an error didn't occured. Then I would probably make another question on SO about why cron job unexpectedly stops.